# Select an element with it's background color is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check my code. The  condition for checking the background color are not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/oL7tdL22/1/

```js
$(function(){

$(".testing").each(function(){
   if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255,193,0)"){
     alert("found");
   }
   else{
     alert("not found");
   }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(255,193,0)">
Test
</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(220, 4, 81)">
Test
</div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(0, 186, 76)">
Test
</div>
</div>
```

When we are alert background color, it's working. But we cannot match the colors.

Comment: When I run the alert, there are spaces after each comma. Adding the spaces seems to do the trick.

Comment: I remove all spaces and it works fine [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fender/oL7tdL22/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to give a space after each comma in rgb color code like `rgb(255, 193, 0)`. Then it works.

```js
$(function(){

$(".testing").each(function(){
   if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255, 193, 0)"){
     alert("found");
   }
   else{
     alert("not found");
   }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(255,193,0)">
Test
</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(220, 4, 81)">
Test
</div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
<div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(0, 186, 76)">
Test
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to seperate the `rgb` values with a space, as JQuery parses the `.css("background-color")` value this way.

```
rgb(X, Y, Z)
      ▲  ▲
```

This is the correct code:

```
if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255, 193, 0)"){
   alert("found");
}
```

Code snippet:

```js
$(function(){
     $(".testing").each(function(){
        if($(this).css("background-color")=="rgb(255, 193, 0)")
          alert("found");
        else
          alert("not found");
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(255,193,0)">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(220, 4, 81)">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="testing"  style="background-color:rgb(0, 186, 76)">Test</div>
</div>
```